# Como inserir data e hora no oracle? via c#

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação desktop e estava tudo dando certo ate a hora em que tentei inserir a data e a hora gerada pelo C# em uma tabela no oracle. Alguem pode me ensinar a query para inserir a data nesse formata:

```
21/07/2018 12:54:35: (dd/mm/yyyy hh24/mm/ss).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO tabela 
(codigo, datahora ) 
VALUES
(1, TO_DATE(nvl('','19/07/2017 19:49:00'),'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
```

Resolvido :)